# Need guidance in dynamically assigning file name

Tags: python, list

I need help with dynamically assigning a filename when I am exporting from Python. The purpose is to export multiple files where name has to be picked from a list defined. My code is as below

```py
list = ['1' , '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']

for A in list:
    df1 = function(X = ABC, Y = A)

df1.to_csv('C:\\Users\\013830\\PycharmProjects\\pythonProject\\venv\\"%A".csv')
```

What I want is when exporting the filenames should become 1.csv, 2.csv, 3.csv and so on. My above code is returning an error saying invalid argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
list = ['1' , '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']

for A in list:
    df1 = function(X = ABC, Y = A)
    df1.to_csv(f'C:\\Users\\013830\\PycharmProjects\\pythonProject\\venv\\{A}.csv')
```

Comment: This didnt work out. This simply saved one single file with name {A}.csv while i want 6 different files to be saved with name 1.csv / 2.csv / 3.csv etc.

Comment: did you include the `f` at the start of the string?

Comment: My sincere apology, NO I hadn't. It works like a charm . I am accepting this as an answer.